# Having serious Issues creating a multiplication table using nested-loops and 2D arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I was instructed to create this multiplication table that also has a search function, but I am very weak at creating loops and this is barely my second time coding arrays...The part that confuses me most is how exactly to code the search function. Also, the assignment asks to use

> intTable.GetLength(0) and intTable.GetLength(1)

to go down and across, respectively. As for the type of loops, just said "loops", so would it have been better to try **for-loops** instead of **while-loops?**

Here is my (horrible) code that I have been messing with for a few days:

```
    namespace CS12c
{
    public partial class frmCS12c : Form
    {

        int [ , ] intTable = new int[9,9];  // 9 x 9 table 

        public frmCS12c()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoadArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            int intResult; //result
            string strSpace; //space

            //Index references begin at zero 
            r = 0;
            while (r < 9)
            { 
                (r = 0; r < intTable.GetLength(0); r++);

                c = 0;
                    while (c < 9)
                    {  
                        (c = 0; c < intTable.GetLength);
                        if (intTable[r, c] < 10)
                            strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
                        else
                        strSpace = " ";   //one space   

                       }
                    }
                    //Add 1 to the indexes before multiplying to build multiplication table 
                    //Use intTable.GetLength(0) and intTable.GetLength(1) to control processing
                    intResult = (r + 1) * (c + 1);
                    intTable[r, c] = intResult;
            }
                txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Delete this after implementation

    }
}

        //Modify the nested for loops used above to nested while loops
        private void btnDisplayArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            string strSpace;

            txtTable.Clear(); //clear the text box

             r = 0;

             while (r < 9)
          {

              c = 0;

             while (c < 9)
            {

            if (intTable[r, c] < 10)
                strSpace = "  ";  //two spaces 
            else
                strSpace = " ";   //one space

            txtTable.AppendText(strSpace); // insert space
            txtTable.AppendText(intTable[r, c].ToString());  //insert result
            c++;
        }

        r++; 
        txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  //Move down one line
}

}
       private void btnSearchArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
            int r; //row
            int c; //column
            int intSearchNumber;

            txtTable.Clear(); //clear the text box

           //Not enclosed in a try-catch; make you enter a number in textbox
           intSearchNumber = int.Parse(txtSearchNumber.Text); 

           while  (r = 0; r < intTable.GetLength(0); r++)
           {

           while  (c = 0; c < intTable.GetLength(1); c++)
           {

              if (intSearchNumber == intTable[r, c])
            {


           txtTable.AppendText("\r\n");  

           //In search display all occurences that match the search numbers
        }


        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }//end of form
}//end of namespace
```

Any assistance would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be a bit confused about `for` and `while` loops, mixing their syntax together, and adding what look like bits of `for` loops in places that they don't exist.

You can usually achieve the same result with either a `for` or `while` loop. For example this `while` loop:

```
        int r = 0;
        while (r < 9)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
            r++;
        }
```

Outputs the exact same thing as this `for` loop:

```
        for (int r = 0; r < 9; r++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(r);
        }
```

The `for` loop looks a bit neater to me, but if you prefer the `while` loop, that's fine too. The only slight difference between them is that the variable `r` doesn't exist after the `for` loop has finished, which is usually considered to be a good thing as you might accidentally use it.

There are other times when a `while` loop makes a lot of sense, for example to keep doing something until there is a change in state, in this case when the stack becomes empty:

```
        Stack<string> s= new Stack<string>(new string[] {"apples", "and", "oranges"});
        while (s.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.Pop());
        }
```

Here's a cleaned up version of your first method, which might help you understand a little better. You had all of the pieces, just needed to fit them together and remove redundant and incorrect code:

```
    private void btnLoadArray_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < intTable.GetLength(0); r++)
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < intTable.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                int intResult = (r + 1) * (c + 1);
                intTable[r, c] = intResult;
            }
        }
    }
```